# Change foreground color of a region (temporarily)

Tags: faces, region, text-properties

I need to change the "OBJECT" string foreground color (let's say "red") in all the occurrences of the string "\command{OBJECT}" in my buffer and I need to restore the original foreground color at the end of the job.

I figured out to do something like (it's a simplified MWE):

```el
(defun propertize-command-arg ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward-regexp "\\\\command{\\([a-z]+\\)}" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (let ((b (match-beginning 1))
              (e (match-end 1)))
          (put-text-property b e SOMETHING))))))
```

`SOMETHING` is what I've not be able to understand/find. I tried also `add-text-properties` and `add-face-text-property`.

Please keep in mind I need to do it temporarily. I'll restore the original appearance of the text at the end of my job (script).

Comment: What does "job (script)" mean? Do you mean an interactive command by that? Why do you need fontification for that? Do you run a `recursive-edit` session? Or maybe, do you fontify for printing or `htmlize-buffer`? It is often better to mention your **primary task** instead of some problem on the way of its solution.

Comment: @Tobias, I'm exploring some `emac`'s features to speed up and make more confortable my `LaTeX` typesetting tasks. In this particular case I simply want to highlight some text (not easily detectable by regexp) during some `query-replace` routines. I'm also exploring the fontification as a method to discriminate region in my replacing routines (see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/47302/15606).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to fontify the buffer yourself.

I describe here a method that works in buffers with `font-lock` activated.

Add the keywords with `font-lock-add-keywords` as long as you need them and remove them afterwards with `font-lock-remove-keywords`.
After such actions you should invalidate the buffer fontification with `font-lock-flush`.

This method has two main advantages:

1. It fontifies the buffer just in time. Only the visible part of the buffer is fontified. The fontification is extented as needed when the visible part of the buffer changes.
2. The keyword is also highlighted in parts of the buffer that you insert/modify after the keyword has been added.

There follows example code that shows how keywords can be added to `font-lock`.

```el
(defface propertize-command-arg-face
  '((t (:foreground "Red")))
  "Face for highlighting command args with `propertize-command-arg'.
I am a bit lazy here and do not differentiate the faces terminal-wise.
See (info \"(elisp) Defining Faces\") for details."
  :group 'latex)

(defvar propertize-command-arg-keywords nil
  "Keywords highlighted by `propertize-command-arg'.")

(setq propertize-command-arg-keywords
      '(("\\\\command{\\([a-z]+\\)}" 1 'propertize-command-arg-face)))

(defun propertize-command-arg ()
  "Highlight command arguments in current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   propertize-command-arg-keywords
   )
  (font-lock-flush))

(defun unpropertize-command-arg ()
  "Unhighlight command arguments in current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (font-lock-remove-keywords
   nil
   propertize-command-arg-keywords)
  (font-lock-flush))
```

You indicated in the comments that you want to use the command with
`latex-mode` and that your MATCHER should also match more general
arguments of LaTeX macros. The [Elisp Manual describes that you can
also use functions as matchers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html). That function can use `scan-sexps` for parsing the macro argument.
The following Elisp code defines a new function `propertize-command-scanner` as matcher and
re-defines the keywords list for `font-lock-add-keywords` to use `propertize-command-scanner`.
Also note the comments given in the source code.

```el
(defun propertize-command-scanner (bound)
  "Search for LaTeX macro \\command{...}.
Start at point and do not search beyond BOUND.
Set match data such that the embraced macro
argument is the first group."
  (when
      (let (found)
    (while (and (search-forward "\\command" bound t)
            ;; avoid matches in strings and comments
            (null (setq found
                (null
                 (nth 8
                      (syntax-ppss (point))))))))
    found)
    (let* ((b (match-beginning 0))
       (comment-forward most-positive-fixnum) ;; also skips whitespace
       (b1 (point))
       (parse-sexp-ignore-comments t)
       (e1 (scan-sexps b1 1)))
      (set-match-data (list b e1 b1 e1 (current-buffer)))
      (goto-char e1))))

(setq propertize-command-arg-keywords
      '((propertize-command-scanner 1 'propertize-command-arg-face t)))
;; OVERRIDE must be non-nil since fontification of $...$ is syntax based
;; and syntax based fontification comes first.
```

---

I only outline a strategy for the case that `font-lock` is not active:
Define your own special face as it is done above for the `font-lock` case.
You can register a fontification function via `jit-lock-register`.
That function gets the boundaries of the region to be fontified
and should set the `face` property of the text-stretches that match your keyword.

When you want to get rid of the highlighting for your keyword search for the stretches of text that have
your special face as face property and remove their face property.

Comment: Very helpful and interesting. Your method has however the disadvantage that needs regexp to intercept the region to be highlighted/propertized. What if I have `\command{Some text $\frac{\mathcal{Z}\times\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{\bar{t}}}$ \emph{other text}}`?

Comment: (Actually I can write a regexp that matchs multiple nested `{ }` groups, but I have experienced some stack overflow issues.)

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I added a possible modification for handling the case of nested groups in LaTeX macro arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `SOMETHING` by `'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red")` or `'face '(:foreground "red")`.

You want `font-lock-face` when font-locking is active, otherwise property `face` is correct.

Please look at [EmacsWiki Text Properties](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TextProperties) for more explanation.

Comment: It works but I don't have yet any idea to undo the fontification (I mean restore the previous fontification). Any suggestion?

Comment: Ok, I tried `(remove-list-of-text-properties (point-min) (point-max) '(font-lock-face))`. It removes the fontification keeping untouched the sintax highlighting of the buffer. Could be it the right way to do that?